# Using Windows libraries with cgo

Tags: windows, go, cgo

I'm trying to build a Go package which makes use of [TagLib](http://taglib.github.io/), and I'm having a little trouble figuring out exactly how to use the compiled libraries with cgo.

I've compiled TagLib, which has spit out `tag.dll`, `tag.exp`, and `tag.lib` in the `taglib` dir. There were also the `taglib_c.*` binaries in the bindings directory, but I'm assuming that I just ignore those.

How do I make use of the compiled libraries for use with Go? I have everything setup in the source from the project on OS X, but what do I need to do to make it compile on Windows? Does the compiled library (dll or static lib?) have to be in the same directory as the source? What about the headers?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32) help? It doesn't use cgo, but it instead does this: `syscall.NewLazyDLL("ole32.dll")`. This is useful since it can be cross-compiled easily (I don't use Windows so this is a major plus). I don't know if this will work for your library though.

Comment: @tjameson I'll definitely give this a good look either tonight or tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't have a windows machine available to try this out myself, but *theoretically*, this should work.  The steps I have listed are written with a unix perspective, but it should be directly translatable to Windows unless otherwise noted. For Windows, I like to use [GitBash](http://git-scm.com/download/win) for my terminal as it comes with some useful unix tools.

Anyways, I'm gonna work through the entire process to make sure I'm not making any assumptions.  first, we'll start with downloading and installing taglib.  Assuming that you've downloading the [1.8 tarball](http://taglib.github.io/releases/taglib-1.8.tar.gz) that they have available, then I would install it locally in some folder in my computer:

```
/home/noj $ mkdir -p clibs/src
/home/noj $ cd clibs/src
/home/noj/clibs/src $ tar -xvf /home/noj/Downloads/
/home/noj/clibs/src $ cd taglib-1.8
/home/noj/clibs/src/taglib-1.8 $ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/noj/clibs -DCMAKE_RELEASE_TYPE=Release .
/home/noj/clibs/src/taglib $ make
/home/noj/clibs/src/taglib $ make install
```

The above code should install taglib locally for development in the folder `/home/noj/clibs`.  If you take a look at the inside of the folder, you'll find subdirectories for `bin`, `lib`, and `include`.

So here's the funky part.  The Windows standard is to dump dynamic lib files (`*.dll`) into the `bin` directory.  Some open source libraries adhere to this and do that, others still dump the `*.dll` files in the `lib` directory since that's where they usually go in Unix systems.  You'll want to take a look at the `lib` directory generated by the installation and copy any `*.dll` files that are generated over to the `bin` directory to make sure proper linking takes place without too much hackery.

Now for the go source code!  At the top of your source code, you'll want to include the `cgo` meta comments to tell Go where to search for the libraries you want, as well as their headers (the `include` directory generated during the installation).  Here's some Go source that tries to use the libraries we just built above:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/home/noj/clibs/lib -ltag -lstdc++
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/home/noj/clibs/include/taglib

#include <taglib.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
  // normal imports
  // ...
)

func main() {
  // ...
}
```

Now, Windows, also requires you to add the directory where your `*.dll` files live to your `PATH`, so we'll go ahead and do that...

```
/home/noj $ export PATH=$PATH:/home/noj/clibs/bin
```

And now we should be ready to compile the code normally using `go build` within the Go's source directory.

**Possible Problems:**

So some problems you might run into is finding out that you don't have the necessary libraries to build taglib in Windows, though it sounds like you've already built it, so that should be fine.  You'll notice that in the go source I added the `LDFLAG` for the standard c++ library.  This is because taglib uses C++.  If this turns out to be a problem, I would create a simple C program alongside your go code that interfaces with the c++ library and creates a C interface for it.  From my experience, it's a lot easier to work with a C library and Go than with C++ and Go.

Comment: The thing is that there's actually a C binding for the app, which is what the original person who wrote the library which I'm modifying used. [Here](https://github.com/wtolson/go-taglib) is the project. Building on Windows is just turning out to be an overall bitch. Even though I built the library, now I'm having issues with mingw and just decided to give Windows the finger. Thank you for your help.